# API for Experience Editor compliant date logic

Tags: experience-editor

I have an "Expired" date that drives some functionality (e.g. it hides certain controls, disables others, etc.)  I would like this to be wired into the Experience Editor date selector, so that when an author clicks the date past the expiration date, the renderings change appropriately. What Sitecore API should I use to get the date? (Obviously, System.DateTime.Now will not be impacted by the Experience Editor change.

Comment: This answer on SO looks like what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16489149/661447

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WebEditUtil.GetCurrentDate()`

```
var now = DateTime.Now;

if (!Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal)
{
    now = WebEditUtil.GetCurrentDate();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Is the PageMode check required? It looks like this method falls back to UtcNow if the sc_date cookie is not set.  (I guess if you want to avoid UTC then yes, but otherwise it looks like this is fine.)

Comment: Reading my previous comment after a minute's thought. Having GetCurrentDate return UTC would confuse the heck out of people. I think Marek's code is the way to go. Thanks again for the quick response.